# Create react app different public/index.html for production/dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am working on a react app and a js project. So basically two things which are on the same website. Now I want to minify the plain js code in production. My first approach was to concatenate all js files, run them through a compressor lib and include the compressed js lib to index.html. However, I want this only in production so my question is, is it possible to have 2 public/index.html with different includes depending on dev or production? or is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I were you I would create several tasks on the package.json file, something like "*prod*" and "*dev*", I do not know if you are using plain Webpack or create-react-app cli, in my case with Webpack I serve the plain files when I am developing and I generate a dist folder with all the minimized files for production.

Something like this:

```
 "scripts": {
   "prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --mode production",
   "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
},
```

So the main thing to learn here is that you do not need to mantain two index.html files, but create tasks that handle the dev and prod mode for you.

Comment: The thing is that I use createReactApp. Is it possible to do that without ejecting?

Comment: @Alexus you can customize webpack config with `react-app-rewired` on npm.